# Short story with a strange house/mirrored rooms

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

My girlfriend reminded me of a short story I read and am trying to track down but having no luck. The story involves a house that has two identical rooms, mirror copies of each, other if I recall each with a mirror and a chair. Unfortunate person finds themselves lost and wandering and ends up entering the strange house. They sit in one of the chairs and get stuck in a loop where they try to leave but are unable to. They get 'teleported' back to the room each time they try to leave. They watch a mirror copy of themselves leave but are unable to follow. I think that's the end?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! When exactly did you read this?

Comment: ty! iirc I read this from a link someone posted on Twitter to an old pdf, maybe like two yrs ago?